# Firebase analytics streamview

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase blog announce that [Realtime Analytics For Everyone](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/realtime-analytics-for-everyone.html) but still my firebase analytics didn't get Streaview

[image]

So anyone can tell me **How to activate StreamView??**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the blogpost says,

> DebugView from Firebase Analytics are being rolled out to the general
>   public.

If you don't have it already, expect to see the report in the next week or so.

Comment: you can track it during 60seconds: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Latest Firebase dashboard comes default with StreamView and debugView. Only diff would be DebugView helps developers to test if events are programmed as required before publishing to stores.

For more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview